# uvm primer, chapter 11, No actual value has been specified for a formal argument 'parent'

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, uvm

I'm having a problem with the "UVM primer book"...basically none of the code examples in the book work with out filling in pieces that are missing and fixing typos.  For instance if I type in the code examples from chapter 11.  Here's my error message below.  How to fix them?

```
QuestaSim-64 vlog 2020.4 Compiler 2020.10 Oct 13 2020
Start time: 08:54:12 on Nov 09,2021
vlog -work work .\hdl\tinyalu_pkg.sv
-- Compiling package tinyalu_pkg
-- Importing package uvm_pkg
** Error (suppressible): .\hdl\random_test.svh(22): (vlog-13266) No actual value has been specified for a formal argument 'parent' that does not have a default value.
** Error: .\hdl\random_test.svh(22): (vlog-13216) Arg. 'name' of 'new':  Illegal assignment to type 'string' from type 'virtual interface tinyalu_bfm': Assigning an unpacked type to a string requires a cast.
** Error (suppressible): (vlog-13276) .\hdl\random_test.svh(31): Could not find field/method name (execute) in 'random_tester_h' of 'random_tester_h.execute'.
** Error (suppressible): .\hdl\add_test.svh(21): (vlog-13266) No actual value has been specified for a formal argument 'parent' that does not have a default value.
** Error: .\hdl\add_test.svh(21): (vlog-13216) Arg. 'name' of 'new':  Illegal assignment to type 'string' from type 'virtual interface tinyalu_bfm': Assigning an unpacked type to a string requires a cast.
** Error (suppressible): (vlog-13276) .\hdl\add_test.svh(30): Could not find field/method name (execute) in 'add_tester_h' of 'add_tester_h.execute'.
End time: 08:54:13 on Nov 09,2021, Elapsed time: 0:00:01
Errors: 6, Warnings: 0
```

Here's my code:

```
// FILE: tinyalu_pkg.sv
package tinyalu_pkg;
    import uvm_pkg::*;
   `include "uvm_macros.svh"
       
    typedef enum bit[2:0] {
        no_op  = 3'b000,
        add_op = 3'b001, 
        and_op = 3'b010,
        xor_op = 3'b011,
        mul_op = 3'b100,
        rst_op = 3'b111
    } operation_t;
              
    typedef struct {
            byte unsigned        A;
            byte unsigned        B;
            operation_t          op;
    } command_s;


    `include "random_test.svh"
        
endpackage : tinyalu_pkg
```

```
// FILE: top.sv
module top;

    // UVM Framework
    import uvm_pkg::*;
    `include "uvm_macros.svh"
    
    import   tinyalu_pkg::*;       //import all tb classes and types
    `include "tinyalu_macros.svh"  //empty file
    
    tinyalu_bfm       bfm();

    tinyalu DUT (
        .A            (bfm.A), 
        .B            (bfm.B), 
        .op           (bfm.op),
        .clk          (bfm.clk), 
        .reset_n      (bfm.reset_n),
        .start        (bfm.start), 
        .done         (bfm.done), 
        .result       (bfm.result)
    );

    // invoke APIs from uvm_pkg to start test...
    initial begin
        
        uvm_config_db #(virtual tinyalu_bfm)::set(null, "*", "bfm", bfm);
                    
        run_test();  
    end
    
endmodule : top
```

```
   // FILE: random_test.svh
    class random_tester extends uvm_test;
    
       //this is needed to register this class so that +UVM_TESTNAME can find it at the command line
       `uvm_component_utils(random_tester);
    
        virtual tinyalu_bfm bfm;
       
        function new (string name, uvm_component parent);
            super.new(name,parent);
            if(!uvm_config_db #(virtual tinyalu_bfm)::get(null, "*","bfm", bfm))
                $fatal("Failed to get BFM");
        endfunction : new
    
        task run_phase(uvm_phase phase);
            random_tester    random_tester_h;
            //coverage  coverage_h;
            //scoreboard scoreboard_h;
    
            phase.raise_objection(this);
    
            random_tester_h    = new(bfm);
            //coverage_h         = new(bfm);
            //scoreboard_h       = new(bfm);
          
            //fork
            //    coverage_h.execute();
            //    scoreboard_h.execute();
            //join_none
    
            random_tester_h.execute();
            phase.drop_objection(this);
       endtask : run_phase
    
    endclass
```

Comment: the *new* function expects **two** arguments (according to its definition) but you only provided **one**. BTW, why are you trying to instantiate *random_tester* inside a task which **is** a member of this class?  it is supposed to be already instantiate in order to call the task.

Comment: you could have a point... its just printed on page 73 of the "UVM Primer" book that way... any ideas what its suppose to look like?

Comment: Thanks... good tip... I realized they didn't provide "random_tester.svh" in this chapter... and the name of class is really "random_test"

Comment: The author is reachable on LinkedIn and Facebook.  His Facebook has a page for the book.  He would probably welcome feedback/bug reports.

Comment: That's a funny thought given how damaged that book is...

Comment: Are you starting with he files from https://github.com/raysalemi/uvmprimer?

Comment: Thanks.  that's extremely helpful.

Comment: I could have sworn the source code examples for this book has been missing from the uvmprimer website for years... then you keep getting calls about UVM jobs from a million people from india and they can't hire you unless you know it already... makes me thing its a conspiracy since the book was obviously sabotaged.

Answer (score 1):

// Commenting out pieces not provided by Chapter 11...

```
// FILE: tinyalu_pkg.sv
package tinyalu_pkg;
    import uvm_pkg::*;
   `include "uvm_macros.svh"
       
    typedef enum bit[2:0] {
        no_op  = 3'b000,
        add_op = 3'b001, 
        and_op = 3'b010,
        xor_op = 3'b011,
        mul_op = 3'b100,
        rst_op = 3'b111
    } operation_t;
              
    typedef struct {
            byte unsigned        A;
            byte unsigned        B;
            operation_t          op;
    } command_s;


    //`include "coverage.svh"
    //`include "base_tester.svh"
    `include "random_test.svh"
    `include "add_test.svh"   
    //`include "scoreboard.svh"
    //`include "command_monitor.svh"
    //`include "result_monitor.svh"
           
    //`include "env.svh"
        
endpackage : tinyalu_pkg
```

```
// FILE: top.sv
module top;

    // UVM Framework
    import uvm_pkg::*;
    `include "uvm_macros.svh"
    
    import   tinyalu_pkg::*;       //import all tb classes and types
    `include "tinyalu_macros.svh"  //empty file
    
    tinyalu_bfm       bfm();

    tinyalu DUT (
        .A            (bfm.A), 
        .B            (bfm.B), 
        .op           (bfm.op),
        .clk          (bfm.clk), 
        .reset_n      (bfm.reset_n),
        .start        (bfm.start), 
        .done         (bfm.done), 
        .result       (bfm.result)
    );

    // invoke APIs from uvm_pkg to start test...
    initial begin
        
        uvm_config_db #(virtual tinyalu_bfm)::set(null, "*", "bfm", bfm);
                    
        run_test();  
    end
    
endmodule : top
```

```
   // FILE: random_test.svh
    class random_test extends uvm_test;
    
       //this is needed to register this class so that +UVM_TESTNAME can find it at the command line
       `uvm_component_utils(random_test);
    
        virtual tinyalu_bfm bfm;
       

        function new (string name, uvm_component parent = null);       
            super.new(name,parent);
            if(!uvm_config_db #(virtual tinyalu_bfm)::get(null, "*","bfm", bfm))
                $fatal("Failed to get BFM");
        endfunction : new
    
        task run_phase(uvm_phase phase);
            //random_tester    random_tester_h;
            //coverage  coverage_h;
            //scoreboard scoreboard_h;
    
            phase.raise_objection(this);
    
            //random_tester_h    = new(bfm);
            //coverage_h         = new(bfm);
            //scoreboard_h       = new(bfm);
          
            //fork
            //    coverage_h.execute();
            //    scoreboard_h.execute();
            //join_none
    
            //random_tester_h.execute();
            phase.drop_objection(this);
       endtask : run_phase
    
    endclass
```